# JScrollbar scroll per 50 px

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I'm working on a program that includes a scrollbar.
In the program I got a scrollable field of 500px and I want the scrollbar to scroll per 50px.
So I get 10 pages.
I dont want to be able to show 50% of a page I only want to be able to show 1 page at a time.
So how do I change the scroll dimensions?

Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Greets,
And thanks in advance
Bram

Answer (score 4):

You can make the scrollable field implement the `Scrollable` interface, which declares two methods the scroll field will use to decide how far it scrolls, `getScrollableUnitIncrement` (scroll-wheel, clicking the scroll arrow) and `getScrollableBlockIncrement` (clicking the scrollbar's track).

If you're really only ever going to want it to be 50, you can use

```
jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(50);
jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setBlockIncrement(50);
```

However, if the user then drags the scrollbar until half a page is shown (I don't think this behavior can be easily changed), scrolling will still jump 50 pixels and show half of the next page... If you implement `Scrollable`, you can base the amount scrolled on what is currently visible.

Comment: Thx for this since the behavior cant be changed that easily is it possible to use a cardlayout and scroll through the cards?
I know its possible to change the card with buttons so can this be done with a scrollbar?

Comment: @Bram Never done it personally, but seems possible. You wouldn't want to use a scrollpane but rather a stand-alone `JScrollBar` which you listen to with an `AdjustmentListener`. When the listener is notified, figure out the appropriate card and show it. You'd have to configure the scrollbar for it to know how many cards you have, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with you `JScrollPane`

```
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(50);
```

This helps when you scroll with `JScrollPane` buttons up/down but you be able show a half of page by moving knob with mouse.

As alternative I can propose to watch knob position with `AdjustmentListener` and shift scrollPane value manually.

```
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener()
    {
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e)
        {
            scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(e.getValue() / 50 * 50);
        }
    });
```

But I think it isn't good idea. May be somebody will propose better way.